# Contagem de linhas retornando valor errado de linhas

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Olá, gente. Estou escrevendo o código abaixo para ler valores de uma planilha excel, mas acontece que ao compilar o programa, a variavel *int countLine = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;* me retorna o valor a mais de linhas preenchidas na planilha excel, fazendo com que na hora que chega no laço for ele acaba pegando valores nulos e o programa para de rodar. Eu já fiz debug várias vezes, mexi na planilha, fiz até outra planilha, até agora não entendi porque está linha de código está retornando esses valores errados. Alguém pode me dar uma luz ou vivenciou algo parecido?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using OfficeOpenXml;

namespace XmlWithExcel
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pessoas = WriteXmlPessoa();

            foreach (var pessoa in pessoas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ID: {pessoa.Id}\tNome: {pessoa.Nome}\tSexo: {pessoa.Sex}\tCPF: {pessoa.Cpf}\tTipo: {pessoa.Tipo}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<Pessoa> WriteXmlPessoa()
        {
            var response = new List<Pessoa>();

            string pathExcel = @"C:\test.xlsx";
            
            FileInfo fileExcel = new FileInfo(pathExcel);

            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileExcel)) 
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                int countColun = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                int countLine = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                
                for (int line = 2; line <= countLine; line++)
                {
                    var pessoa = new Pessoa
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[line, 1].Value.ToString()),
                        Nome = worksheet.Cells[line, 2].Value.ToString(),
                        Sex = worksheet.Cells[line, 3].Value.ToString(),
                        Cpf = worksheet.Cells[line, 4].Value.ToString(),
                        Tipo = int.Parse(worksheet.Cells[line, 5].Value.ToString())
                    };

                    response.Add(pessoa);
                }
            }

            return response;
        }

    }

    public class Pessoa
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Talvez você pode tentar verificar se as células estão em branco antes de montar o seu objeto Pessoa.

```
var range = worksheet.Cells[line, 1, countLine, countColun];

if (range.All(x => x.Value is null))
{
    continue;
}
```

Caso todas as células estiverem em branco, você "pula" essa linha e continua a execução.

Talvez isso te ajude a lidar com essas linhas em branco.

Comment: A ideia deu certo aqui. Vou colocar a pergunta como respondida, obrigado! 